# Dbus-daemon crash after boot

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, systemd, dbus

Not always, but often, I find this bug on startup, but with nothing that crashes. For now I'm ignoring it, because I repeat, it does not scratch anything on the screen, but is there a solution? Details are in this image -> http://tinyimg.io/i/RaXqsym.jpg

Comment: Your session-level dbus should respawn automatically, so you are correct - it won't affect anything. It merely delays your login by a second or two. There might be a solution, but it's not on the screenshot - you must dig deeper through the error message and your logs. None of my 18.10 systems do that, so it's not a universal problem.

Comment: Ok, so I have to support this.. thanks for info